# What's the keyboard shortcut to switch between qwerty and dvorak on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, dvorak

Is there a way to switch between dvorak and qwerty keyboard layouts on the Mac?

On Windows, I was able to use CTRL+SHIFT each time I wanted to switch back and forth.

Does Mac OS X have this versatile, quick, and easy to use method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Keyboard preference pane, you need to add a Dvorak keyboard to the list of input sources from the Input Sources tab. Then, you can enable the keyboard shortcut for changing keyboard layout under the Shortcuts tab (select Input Sources from the list of categories, then check the shortcuts you want). The default is Command-Space, but you can customize the shortcut. CTRL+SHIFT won't work, since you need at least one non-modifier key in the shortcut.